# Store request.headers in a serialized model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :request_headers
end
```

But when I try to do `@comment.request_headers = request.headers` I get a `TypeError (can't dump anonymous class Class)` exception.

Another way to ask my question: how can I convert `request.headers` into a `Hash`? [It uses a Hash under the covers](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b7529ed1cc7cfd8df5fd1b069e2881d39d3d984c/actionpack/lib/action_controller/headers.rb) so this should be easy, no?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably the memoization in [header.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/headers.rb)

Since it supports a `to_a` so you can simply convert it to an array before serializing.

```
@comment.request_headers = request.headers.to_a
```